# Change of variables where x and z are independent variables.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Transform the equation $(y-z)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + (y+z)\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 0$, taking $x=x(u,v)$ as a function and $u=y-z, v=y+z$ as independent variables.

The answer to the problem has to be: 
$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}=\frac{u}{v}$

I have done other exercises involving change of varibles. However, all the exercises I have done had something in common: the function was $z$ (I mean, it was the function whose derivatives appeared in the given equation). Now that my function is $x$ I do not find a way to solve the problem.

It would be very helpful if someone could tell me the first steps of the correct approach to this kind of problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Idea:** Use the chain rule to derive $z$ with respect to $u$ and $v$. Then, the expected terms $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}$ will appear. After you do that, use the equalities of the change of variables and the original equation to eliminate the derivatives of $z$.

**Complete solution:**

We have
$$z=z(x,y)=z(x(u,v),y(u,v)).$$
Then, by the chain rule,
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u},\qquad 
\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\tag{1}$$

On the other hand, since
$$u=y-z,\qquad v=y+z\tag{2}$$
we have
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \left(\frac{v-u}{2}\right)=-\frac{1}{2},\qquad \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial}{\partial v} \left(\frac{v-u}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \left(\frac{u+v}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2},\qquad \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial}{\partial v} \left(\frac{u+v}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$
Substituting in $(1)$, we obtain
$$-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y},\qquad 
\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$
and thus
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\cdot\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\right)\tag{3}$$
Now, substituting $(2)$ and $(3)$ in the original equation
$$(y-z)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + (y+z)\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 0,$$
we get the desired result.